# javaFX as a webservice client?

Tags: web-services, javafx

I need to make calls to a web service from a JavaFX client.

Is there some sort of wsimport type tool that I can use to generate JavaFX client stubs from a deployed WSDL?

Answer (score 2):

JavaFX Supports only RESTfull webservices out of the box. You can however use existing Java tools for generating WSDL stubs and use the generated classes from your JavaFX Script classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could make Java class stubs and call them from javaFX.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

Suppose you have a "MyJavaClass.java"

```
import somePackadge.MyJavaClass
...

var myObject:MyJavaClass = new MyJavaClass();

myObject.setSomething("this is something");

println("{myObject.getSomething()}");

...
```

Refer to "http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/scripting/javafx/javafx_and_java/" for more information